# Generating RSS in Asp.Net MVC 3 returns plain XML

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, rss

I'm following a tutorial where the author inherits from ActionResult to create RssViewResult class that will return RSS. When I run the code and go to the action method that returns RssViewResult as a result the plain XML file appeares. I'm new to RSS and seems like in this tutorial there is no special view that has been created.
Do I need to create a view or I made a mistake in my code?
Here is the code:

```
public class RssViewResult : ActionResult
{
    public RssViewResult(SyndicationFeed feed)
    {
        RssFeed = feed;
    }
    public SyndicationFeed RssFeed { get; set; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var resp = context.HttpContext.Response;
        resp.ContentType = "application/rss+xml";

        var rss = new Rss20FeedFormatter(RssFeed);
        using (var xml = XmlWriter.Create(resp.Output))
        {
            rss.WriteTo(xml);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the action method that returns RSS:

```
    public RssViewResult RssFeed()
    {
        var feed = new SyndicationFeed("News", "Store news",
                                       new Uri(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri))
            {
                Items = _itemsRepository
                    .GetItems()
                    .Select(i =>
                            new SyndicationItem(
                                i.Product.Name,
                                i.Product.Description,
                                new Uri(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)))
            };

        return new RssViewResult(feed);
    }
```

Comment: Where are u viewing the XML ?

Comment: I think nowhere) Can You explain how to create a view that will render rss?

Comment: Firefox detects RSS feeds and does render them accordingly. I know for sure that chrome needed a plugin till few months back.

Comment: thank You! everything works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML is the view itself!

Firefox detects the XML and renders it as a RSS reader would. I know for sure that Chrome needed a plugin (but this was 6 months back when I last checked).

You can style RSS with CSS for the RSS readers by adding

```
<?xml-stylesheet type= "text/css" href="rss.css"?>
```

**Update**

This question and its related answer [How to Add CSS Reference to .NET SyndicationFeed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940887/how-to-add-css-reference-to-net-syndicationfeed) gives a good reference about how to add css using `SyndicationFeed`